# How to use fastify + nestjs + firebase functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, nestjs, fastify

I am using NestJS and Cloud Functions, because of performance I want to switch to Fastify.

But I have no idea what to pass to `functions.https.onRequest(???)`

My old code for express is:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const server: express.Express = express();

const startNestApplication = async (expressInstance: express.Express) => {
  const adapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressInstance);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, adapter, {});
  app.enableCors();
  await app.init();
  return app;
};

const main = startNestApplication(server);

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(server);
```

And new code is:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const startNestApplication = async () => {
  const adapter = new FastifyAdapter();
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(AppModule, adapter, {});
  app.enableCors();
  await app.init();
  return app;
};

const main = startNestApplication();

export const api = functions.https.onRequest(???);
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance

Comment: If Fastify doesn't somehow integrate with an express app as your first code sample shows, then there is not just a simple argument to pass here.  You will have to build an express app to wrap it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an anonymous function to pass as an argument as specified in here[1].

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events